# Assign value to interface element without previous instantiation of the implementation

Tags: codesys

I have a STRUCT (DUT) which one element is an interface.

```
STRUCT myStruct
   element : iInterf;
END_STRUCT
```

In declaration session, I have to instantiate first (with same implementation) before assign value to this element.

```
instance : iInterf_implementation := (some initialization values);
myVar : myStruct := ( element := instance );
```

Is possible to assign value and instantiate an interface element without create another variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that I know of. Here's a quote from the CODESYS [documentation](https://help.codesys.com/api-content/2/codesys/3.5.17.0/en/_cds_obj_interface/): `CODESYS always treats variables declared with the type of an interface as references`. If an interface is essentially a reference, which is essentially a pointer, then you need a variable for the interface to refer/point at.

Comment: A structure, as myStruct, should be a pointer too, isn't?. Even though I can declare an initial value. I assume that compile create a variable when initial value is defined.

Comment: There's no mention of structures being pointers in the [documentation](https://help.codesys.com/api-content/2/codesys/3.5.17.0/en/_cds_datatype_structure/). Moreover, In any language that I know, structures are NOT pointers. They're value types, just a block of consecutive memory holding multiple types.